# Rspec 2.14, FactoryGirl 4.2, Rails 3.2.11 - has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to FactoryGirl (and testing in general) and I'm trying to set up a factory for a has_many though relationship. All of the examples I've found so far have been using older versions of factory girl and the official documentation hasn't been that helpful.

When I run my test it says:

```
Failures:

  1) Brand has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:brand).should be_valid
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Styles can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/brand_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**brand.rb**

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible               :title,
                                :style_ids

  has_many                      :brand_styles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many                      :styles,       through: :brand_styles

  validates_presence_of         :title
  validates_presence_of         :styles
end
```

**style.rb**

```
class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible               :title

  has_many                      :brand_styles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many                      :brands,       through: :brand_styles

  validates_presence_of         :title
end
```

**brand_style.rb**

```
class BrandStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :brand_id, 
                  :style_id

  belongs_to      :brand
  belongs_to      :style
end
```

**factories**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :brand do
    title "Some Brand"

    after(:create) do |brand| 
      brand.style create(:brand_style, brand:brand, style: FactoryGirl.build(:style))
      brand.reload
    end
  end

  factory :style do
    title "Some Style"
  end

  factory :brand_style do
    brand
    style
  end
end
```

**spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Brand do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:brand).should be_valid
  end
end
```

**---EDIT---**

I've modified my factory per Damien Roches suggestion and am now getting this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Brand has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:brand).should be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `primary_key' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x007fc581b2d178>
     # ./spec/factories/brand.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/brand_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Modified factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :brand do |brand|
    brand.title "Some Brand"
    brand.styles { build_list(:brand_style, 1, brand: brand, style: build(:style)) }
  end

  factory :style do
    title "Some Style"
  end

  factory :brand_style do
    brand
    style
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `after(:create)` block with this:

```
styles { build_list(:brand_style, 1, brand: brand, style: build(:style)) }
```

My `factory_girl` knowledge is a little rough, so let me know if you have further trouble and I'll reply when I get chance.

Couple of notes. You can't use `after(:create)` because your `brand` model requires `styles`. You cannot use `brand.style` because the relationship is `has_many`. That should be `brand.styles`. With that, you cannot use `brand.styles = create()` because the assignment expects an array. You could use `brand.styles = [create()]` but I prefer `create_list`.

I've replaced `create(:brand_style)` with `build`. Test different variations as I've found at times the association will not save when you save the parent object depending on your configuration. See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) for details.

Comment: I've updated my code (above) per your suggestion and am now getting a new error `undefined method 'primary_key' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x007fc581b2d178>`. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you update your `:brand` block? It should be as per `:style` and `:brand_style`. Do not pass in `|brand|`. Use same format as other factories. Can't be sure that is issue, but correct that first. If the error persists, it could be an incompatibility between your version of `rails` and `factory_girl`.

Comment: Originally I had just updated `create(:after)` block they way you specified, however, when I ran the test it was failing with `undefined method 'brand'` on the `brand: brand` portion which lead me to add the `|brand|`. I'll try updating the format of the other factories to use `|whatever|` to eliminate that possibility. Also, for reference I'm using rails 3.2.11